# Object ArrayList over socket

Tags: java, sockets, object, arraylist

I have to pass an ArrayList over tcp socket (Server > Client) over the network. When I pass and Arraylist of Strings it works fine and the client is able accept the ArrayList and and print. but when the ArrayList is off Objects I have many exceptions and it does not work. Have a look below please.

**Server**

```
    ArrayList<Database> List = new ArrayList<>(); //Database is a seperate class
    Database item1 = new Database();
            item1.code = "1568";
    item1.name = "Round Table";
    item1.details = "Ikeas best Seller";
    item1.inStock = "17";
    List.add(item1);
```

...

```
ObjectOutputStream oout = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
oout.writeObject(List);
```

**Client**

```
ObjectInputStream iin =  new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
Object items = iin.readObject();
```

Using this code I have many Exceptions thrown. If I replace the array with a string type array like `ArrayList<String> Items = new ArrayList<>();` It will work fine. Any Ideas? I am really stack here. Thank You!

Comment: Can we see at least one exception out of those many?

Comment: Does client has Database class in its classpath?

Comment: Is `Database` class serializable? If not, you need to serialize it to send it.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the stacktraces instead of putting them as comments, thanks. This will make it easier to people wanting to help you.

Comment: So, I need to add the Serializable library in all three classes I have, client, server, and database right?

Comment: Just make it implement serializable and you're done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object you are putting in the list and sending must implement the Serializable interface. That also means that fields within that class will also have to be Serializable.

Comment: Thank you! I am not advanced in java at all, but after your answer I searched more I solved the problem. I was searching for wrong things, thanks for indicating and for the solution!